# UbuntuMATE on Lenovo MiiX320 - mobile broadband grayed out

Tags: networking, network-manager, lenovo, mobile-broadband

I've installed Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 on a Lenovo MiiX320 by following this tutorial: [UbuntuMATE auf MiiX320-10icr](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ubuntu-auf-lenovo-ideapad-miix-320-10icr-80xf0/)

It works fine, but I can't connect by using the built-in Fibocom LTE modem. It's displayed at the Network Manager applet immediately as a mobile broadband connection, incl. the provider and field-strength. However, the entry is grayed out and I can't access it and so I couldn't enable the connection. In the settings menu of the Network Manager, the connection is not listed. If I manually create a mobile broadband connection, the applet starts to flicker in the status line.

I've already tried to get help at the ubuntu-users forum, but unfortunately, the best is now over with their ideas.
[Fibocom-LTE-Modem lässt sich nicht aktivieren](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/fibocom-lte-modem-laesst-sich-nicht-aktivieren/2/)

If you read the thread @ ubuntuusers, then you see what already has been queried and. Unfortunately, there was no success. If anyone else has an idea (or maybe even the solution to the problem): I beg for it! :)